# Multiple terms in a facet

Tags: lucene, faceted-search

I'm currently facing a Lucene facet problem.

My document looks like:

```
doc1:
 - title: lorem
 - facetField: east west

doc2:
 - title: ipsum
 - facetField: north

doc3:
 - title: dolor
 - facetField: south

doc4:
 - title: sit 
 - facetField: north west
```

I would like to use facets to narrow down my search results for documents which only contain the text `west`.

As far as I know, the `new CategoryPath("categoryFacet", "west")` wouldn't find any documents because it does not exactly match a document. Is there a possibility to use something like *contains term* in facets?

Comment: How about having multivalued `facetField` with two values (`north` and `west`)?

Comment: I tried a multivalued field, but Lucene would only find the documents for the value which was indexed first..